# Cannot read cells of a data frame with whitespace between words in R

Tags: r, whitespace

Hello I am facing a strage problem. Suppose that i have this dataframe below:

```
location = c("100 ail","16th and Whitmore","40AB01 - ANTWERPEN","Abington") 
last = c("2018-02-01 09:30:00", "2018-02-01 03:00:00", "2017-03-07 10:00:00","2018-02-01 03:00:00") 
first = c("2015-09-01 00:00:00","2016-03-06 19:00:00","2016-11-22 15:00:00","2016-06-09 19:00:00") 
df = data.frame(location, last, first)
```

As you can see there are white spaces between words which cannot be read when i use them in `aq_measurements()`. It only reads cells without spaces between words. I do not want neither to replace them with a comma nor unite the 2 or more words but somehow to keep them as they are but be able to read them in my dataframe. As you can see if you call the function below it gives results only for "Abingdon" which is one word.

```
library(ropenaq)
datdat<- aq_measurements(location="100 ail")
```

This is how `aq_measurements()` is generally used:

`dat<- (aq_measurements(country = “country”, city = “city”, location = “location”, parameter = “pollutant choice”, date_from = “YYYdateY-MM-DD”, date_to = “YYYY-MM-DD”)`.

Comment: This code does not illustrate your error! You're asking us to magically debug what happens when you call `ropenaq::aq_measurements()`. A package that most of us have never heard of, let alone installed or run. So post both the code that calls it, and the error it gives!

Comment: I want a general answer about the whitespace issue. It does not have to do with the function but ok i will provide it.

Comment: 99.9% of users have never run `ropenaq::aq_measurements()`. I had to to Google it just to see what package it was. You're not going to get any/many answers unless you show us what the specific error is. Ideally we could diagnose it without needing to install that package.

Comment: i just editted it

Comment: you were right! i had to be more specific. thanks a lot!

Comment: See, it was an issue specific to a package almost noone here had ever heard of, let alone used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this tutorial](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/ropenaq_tutorial/) for ropenaq, the example for this function replaces whitespace with +-signs.  In your example, you should try something like: `location = "100+ail"`